# Cant get table to display properly on a phone (pivot table)

Tags: html, css

This code will display properly on a resized desktop browser and on codepen on mobile. It will not display properly by itself on mobile safari or chrome. If anyone has time I would really appreciate some help figuring out why. I am ending up with nothing in any of the rows except for the first which contains all of the "td" tags for some reason.

The table is supposed to pivot and have the rows displayed as columns with the headers' positions fixed while the new columns can be scrolled through.

Screenshot from my phone:
[image: This is a screenshot from my phone of what the code ends up displaying]

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

    #tableContainer .cf::after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
    #tableContainer * html .cf { zoom: 1; }
    #tableContainer *:first-child+html .cf { zoom: 1; }

    #tableContainer table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: block; position: relative; }

    #tableContainer th,
    #tableContainer td { margin: 0; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid #0000001A; height: 45px; }
    #tableContainer thead { display: block; float: left;}
    #tableContainer tbody { display: block; width: auto; position: relative; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap; }
    #tableContainer thead tr { display: block; }
    #tableContainer th { display: block; text-align: left; border-right: 2px solid black; }
    #tableContainer tbody tr { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
    #tableContainer td { display: block;  text-align: left; }

    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Header 1 </th>
            <th> Header 2 </th>
            <th> Header 3 </th>
            <th> Header 4 </th>
            <th> Header 5 </th>
            <th> Header 6 </th>
            <th> Header 7 </th>
            <th> Header 8 </th>
            <th> Header 9 </th>
            <th> Header 10 </th>
            <th> Header 12 </th>
            <th> Header 13 </th>
            <th> Header 14 </th>
            <th> Header 15 </th>
            <th> Header 16 </th>
            <th> Header 17 </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">
              <button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title="">data</td>
            <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it to just display with e.g. a horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma It is supposed to be a pivot table. On a phone the rows should be displayed as columns basically. It works when you resize your browser window or look at it on codepen on a phone, however, it does not work when the html file is opened by itself on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up the code, `overflow:auto;` on table should suffice in your case:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #tableContainer .cf::after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
  }
  #tableContainer * html .cf {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  #tableContainer *:first-child+html .cf {
    zoom: 1;
  }
  #tableContainer {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  #tableContainer th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> Header 1 </th>
        <th> Header 2 </th>
        <th> Header 3 </th>
        <th> Header 4 </th>
        <th> Header 5 </th>
        <th> Header 6 </th>
        <th> Header 7 </th>
        <th> Header 8 </th>
        <th> Header 9 </th>
        <th> Header 10 </th>
        <th> Header 12 </th>
        <th> Header 13 </th>
        <th> Header 14 </th>
        <th> Header 15 </th>
        <th> Header 16 </th>
        <th> Header 17 </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">
          <button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title="">data</td>
        <td data-title=""><button class="" id="">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Please check out the code pen link. When the table is displayed on on a phone or on any window that is less than 900 pixels in width, the table should pivot.

Comment: Got it, however your current code works as pivot what is it you need then?

Comment: It doesn't work as pivot on phones. When the html is displayed by itself on a phone, not in codepen, it is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Without seeing the issue it is difficult to fix right? mean we can fix things what we see not  on assumption. I will take out my answer.

Comment: Just updated my post with a picture of what the code displays on my phone as well as other's who I have asked to test it.

Comment: @lbertoni I got the issue here, but what I am trying to say is, the codepen shows as pivot and I cannot recreate the issue to fix is what I am trying to convey, btw your code pen is no longer available.

Comment: I purposely removed the codepen because it showed what is supposed to happen, not what actually happens on phones.

Comment: which browser are you using in phone? and is it happening with all the phone browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I found the solution but I found the cause of the problem. For some reason on mobile browsers the #tableContainer td { display: block; text-align: left; } never gets executed and I can't force it using jquery either.